# jQuery Mobile - Include Footer from External File

Tags: jquery, dynamic, mobile, footer, navbar

I would like to create a shared footer (e.g. footer.html) that can be used by all of the pages in my jQuery Mobile application.     However, I cannot find a way to get jQuery to refresh the styles in the footer navbar after loading the html from the external file.  After thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Footer.html:

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="CSS" data-grid="d" id="footerNav">
    <ul >
        <li ><a href="#" id="a" data-icon="custom"><div>a</div></a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" id="b" data-icon="custom"><div>b</div></a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" id="c" data-icon="custom"><div>c</div></a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" id="d" data-icon="custom"><div>d</div></a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" id="e" data-icon="custom"><div>e</div></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Index.html:

```
<div data-role="page" style="position: relative" data-theme="a" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="homebutton" onclick="location.href='default.html'">
            &nbsp;</div>
        <h1>
            EVENT CALENDAR</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build you first
            jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax
            to support the animated page transitions.</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="CSO" data-position="fixed" id="footerDiv">

    </div>

    <script>
    $('#index').live('pageinit', function (event, ui) {
         $('#footerDiv').load('Shared/Footer.html');
         [Some code to refresh the footer so it gets redrawn by Jquery Mobile]  
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the rest of the code is valid:

```
$('#footerDiv').load('Shared/Footer.html').trigger("create");
```

Comment: yes the closest still, best answer, but not exactly the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

for me, I had to use the callback function, and add it in my pageinit event :

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){
  $("#footerDiv").load('_footer.html', function(){$(this).trigger("create")});
});
```

Comment: thanks. but it will remove my all contant and add a footer only. i just want to append the footer. Do you have some idea?