# jQuery and PhoneGap - Include a HTML file clientside with HTML or JS?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, include

I'm creating an native Android application by using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

When I create a multipaged page, i don't to include the same navigationbar all the time.
So I tried to include a (s)html. But it doesn't work.
This is what i've tried this far:

```
<!--#include file="navigation.inc.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="navigation.inc.html" -->
<!--#include file="navigation.inc.shtml" -->
<!--#include virtual="navigation.inc.shtml" -->
```

This page is not placed on a (web)server.
When the navigation.inc.shtml is not a server, is it possible to include the file with html or javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue. As far as I can tell, Android ignores Server Side Includes.

I've been getting close to the answer with [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/%20load) based on this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974630/jquery-mobile-include-footer-from-external-file) but I'm taking a slightly different approach:

Wherever you need to include an external file:

```
<div data-include="footer"></div>
```

Then, at the end of my ( multipage ) index.html

```
$('div[data-include]').each(function() {
    $(this).load( $(this).attr('data-include') + '.html').trigger('create');
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for the initial page view. Any subsequent pages look great.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974630/jquery-mobile-include-footer-from-external-file

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to a write-once approach to data-role="footer"s, and got it working as shown below.  What I don't like it 1.) its not from an include file so 2.) the navbar code is a bit hard to read and maintain.  (This code does NOT go in document.ready.)

```
var myFooter = '<div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#myPageName" >Send</a></li><li><a href="#myPageTwo" >Set Up</a></li><li><a href="#myPageThree" >Help</a></li></ul></div>';

// use this code pointing to each data-role="footer" where you want this navbar
$('div#myPageName').live("pagebeforecreate", function(){
      $('div#myFooterName').html(myFooter)
})
```

the pagecreate event works too.

Answer (score 1):

I used the client side javascript code as suggested above from Jhof.

template example for Navigation header:

```
<body onLoad="initialization()">
....
  <div template-include="nav-header">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadTemplates() 
    { 
  $('div[template-include]').each(function() {
      $(this).load('tpl/' + $(this).attr('template-include') + '.html').trigger('create');
});
    } 
    function initialization() {
      ....
      loadTemplates();
      ....
    }
  </script>

<body>
```

I've created an initialization function where I call all my init functions as `loadTemplates()`

my `initializationFunction` is called from `body.onLoad` event. 
`onLoad` event fire at the end of the html parsing!

So it work also at the initial page view.