# PhoneGap: include files without javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i need to use phonegap for an android app, and i need to include a header file in every page, but i don't want to make it by scripting.

is there a way to do that (templating?), or i must use javascript to do that?
i've seen this thread, but it's not what i'm looking for fully:
[jQuery and PhoneGap - Include a HTML file clientside with HTML or JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003402/jquery-and-phonegap-include-a-html-file-clientside-with-html-or-js)

thanks all for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to include HTML on your pages (SSI, PHP, ASP, JS...). But because of PhoneGap (remember that PhoneGap doesn't act as a server) you cant use server side technologies to include HTML, so SSI, PHP and ASP are out.

JS is the only remaining valid option. Why do not you use it ? Anyway, you will have to use JS with the PhoneGap API.

The meaning of this operation is to avoid duplicating the code, right ?

Comment: thanks for your answer!
typically, i want to make header / footer templates, but how can i include that in a page wich haven't been loaded yet?

i just don't want to duplicate code, of course!

Comment: I had the same problem a few months ago. In my opinion, you have two valid solutions :
1/ Use JS to include your HTML template
2/ Make a onepage website with different pages (jQuery mobile allows to do it that way)
Code duplicating is always such a pain...
If you choose the JS way of course you'll have to wait until the page is completely loaded to add to your DOM header and your footer.

Comment: i don't really have the choice! it will be one page + js tol oad what i need.
thks for help

Comment: Et si tu trouves d'autres solutions je suis preneur également. Je continue de mon côté à tester et trouver LA meilleure solution pour ce genre de problème. (oui j'ai vu que ton profil était en Français c'est plus facile comme ça ^^)

Comment: ça marche!
ce qui m’embête le plus c'est pour loader le header, j'aimerais pouvoir switcher entre 2 modeles facilement selon les pages, et pas avoir une grosse structure dont la moitié du code ne pas pas servir une fois sur 2....

Comment: C'est sur que niveau optimisation c'est le must, d'autant plus que sur mobile les ressources ne sont pas les mêmes que sur un Desktop.