# Jquery Mobile Same Footer on Different Pages

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic, cordova, footer

I want to have the same header and footer on all pages on my jquery mobile app and control it using a different file for example like footer.html. This is easy to do use PHP include but I can't because I am planning on using this app with phonegap.

Searching around I found using

```
  <div data-role="footer">
<div class="footerExt"></div>
  </div>
```

and javascript

```
$('.footerExt').load('footer.html')
```

However this is not working. I should mention that I am javascript beginner, I barely understand what going on.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with following event, it works with my code:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
            $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function(){
                $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
            });
        });
```

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/2880107) shows the entire code.

Comment: This worked well but any idea how to make it work with ui-btn-active? Or is it even possible because if I add the class to the buttons all the buttons show up as active on the home page.

Comment: ideally you should apply the theme to distinguish one button from other http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html

Comment: Better solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974630/jquery-mobile-include-footer-from-external-file

Answer (score 1):

from jquery 1.9 and above [live is now deprecated](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) please use the function with on. In console it will give TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

example
change your code

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
            $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function(){
                $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
            });
        });
```

**Replace with**

```
 $('[data-role=page]').on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
                $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function(){
                    $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the external html code to an div with a data-role="footer",
so you need to change the:

```
<div class="footerExt"></div>
```

**to**

```
<div data-role="footer" class="footerExt"></div>
```

and for example your footer html could have a h3

```
  <h3>This is your footer</h3>
```

Comment: My code now looks like this:

'<div data-role="footer">
<div data-role="footer" class="footerExt"></div>
  </div>'

But unfortunately its still not working. Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks