# Keep navbar on all pages with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation, cordova

I'm currently creating phonegap app using jquery mobile framework.

I have multiple pages, like this :

- index.html (global layout)
- home.html (home page)
- settings.html
  (settings page)
- ...

I want to have the navbar on every page, and keep it without duplicate it on every page (home, settings...) and I don't know why I can't do that (like include header.html ? or set navbar in global layout ?).
I browse in my app using link between pages

```
<a href="home.html" data-transition="slide">Home</a>
```

How can I do for keep my navbar ?

Thanks,

Comment: see my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/CxFWh/7/ will insert a navbar based on a navbar string, you can equally use a navbar.html file containing this string (not doable on jsfiddle through)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this post, it appends a common footer to all the pages form a common html file.

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
     $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function(){
           $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar()
     });
});
```

For more info refer this post - [Jquery Mobile Same Footer on Different Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906189/jquery-mobile-same-footer-on-different-pages)

Comment: Great! But how to do that while keeping it persistent to the page? Like [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/navbar/footer-persist-a.html)?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the `navbar()` function?

Answer (score 1):

You must have the navbar element repeated in each `data-role="page"`.
like this [Js Fiddle Work Out](http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/CxFWh/3/)

or as suggested by dhaval, insert it on every page via ajax: but you don't gain much except if you have many tabs

[Js Fiddle Work Out](http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/CxFWh/7/)