# Phonegap How To Reuse/Include HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I know in server side,this can be done easily by the server side script,but `PhoneGap` development focus is on the local copy.So how could I reuse/include a `HTML` page into another HTML page (without violent the Same Origin Policy)?

Comment: Can you provide some Code?

Comment: Have you tried an iframe?

Comment: @TasosBitsios iframe is not what I want, for example, I want to use a customized dialog component (a div container) across all the page, I do not want to copy the HTML content across all the page, so how can I do?

Comment: Have you tried having your dialog component in a separate html file (all the HTML markup, etc) and then loading that via jQuery (.load())?

Comment: @Ekaterina Based on my research (Sorry I haven't tried yet, gonna try it soon), jQuery.load() doesn't allow to load local file right?

Comment: It does allow local files. Give it a whirl!

Comment: have you thought of web components? This doesnt work natively at the moment, but with google's Polymer.js library it works today. Web components are basically what you want, reusable building blocks for the web

Comment: "I want to use a customized dialog component (a div container) across all the page" - have you considered just using a template library for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use many good libraries available while developing an application using `PhoneGap`.If you are aware of `jQuery Mobile` library.Using this library you can include multiple html pages into one single page.I am `PhoneGap` developer.I have developed single page application using this `jQM` library.

They worked on the Ajax navigation.So,no page reloading at the client side.This will make your app performance dramatically.You have `HTML5` localStorage.Store all the data in one ajax hit and navigate through multiple pages.

Here is the link: **[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)**

Additionally you can use **[pager.js](http://pagerjs.com/)** library to load multiple `HTML` pages into one single page.It's very easy to learn.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Incorrect link on the jQuery Mobile FYI - it links to pager.js

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch it with an ajax request and then insert into your page. I use angular.js and this is what it does behind the scenes... You might prefer something simpler like jquery's load function: http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this method in Web browser, we will have Same Origin Policy issue if we try to ajax retrieve a local file. Since phonegap focus on local file, by using ajax, we will have the same issue right?

Comment: If you are developing on your local machine you'll need to run and http server to serve the files. OSX comes with apache, which is what I use, but it's a bit difficult to configure. You can use some sorta LAMP thing or just go to the folder containing your htmls and run "python -m SimpleHTTPServer". SimpleHTTPServer sometimes misses requests but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Loading content via Ajax is the better solution, but JSONP would be an alternative way to loading content with Ajax. JSONP doesn't cause same origin policy issues.

Place your HTML code in a JS file that you load and display via script-tag. E.g.:

JSONP-File:

```
var dialogComponentHTML = "<form>your html code...</form";
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#your_placeholder").html(dialogComponentHTML);
});
```

HTML-File:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dialog.jsonp">
<div id="your_placeholder"></div>
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP