# Couldn't ajax local file from local html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

According to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Corner_cases_and_exceptions), SOP shouldn't apply to file:// protocol, but why my code does not work? I am running this testing page from my local system and I have abc.txt in the same directory as the html page. If I change URL to http://www.google.com/, it does not work too. I don't understand why, could anyone explain?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
    <link href="css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.support.cors = true;
    $(function(){
        $(".btn1").button().click(function(){
            $.ajax({

              url: "abc.txt"

            }).done(function(result) {
              alert("done");
              $(".content").html(result);
            }).fail(function() { 
                alert("error"); 
            });
        });

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn1">Click me!</button>

<div class="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edited:**
The console printed as below:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/yc/Desktop/jquery%20ajax%20testing/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/abc.txt.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

*It does not work for Firefox, IE too.

Comment: Try to set `dataType: "text",` option also in your ajax call..

Comment: you can launch chrome with `--disable-web-security` or `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: what does the console say

Comment: @PalashMondal It still doesn't work.

Comment: @iliacholy It does not only happen for chrome. I use firefox and IE, they have the same problem.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Updated the question, please check.

Comment: that can be done with single line $(selector).load('abc.txt');

Comment: @GMsoF either use jsonp or a server `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: @vishalsharma It doesn't work too. Have tried.

Comment: looks like this is a duplicate question that you already posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623012/phonegap-how-to-reuse-include-html-page

Comment: you need some advanced features of html5 I think plz check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: check permissions on file , see html5 filereader API as mentioned by sakhunzai , try convert abc.txt to abc.html may be error due to web server not allow txt ... now one question .. the file you are running is on server you are browsing with ?.. if yes try directly browsing that like http://localhost/myfiles/abc.txt and see it displays or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a security feature which you can't/won't get around on a client's computer.

In chrome you can disable it by adding the following flag on the command line

`--disable-web-security`

Firefox might have something similar but I don't know it. This is only useful for development purposes and you can't rely on this behaviour in your application.

You should really just use a server ...

Comment: The second option is no longer a valid circumvention - removed via edit.

Comment: @smaudet Edit request denied. Leaving a comment about it is enough and then it will be up to the author of the answer for now to determine if the secondary option should be removed from the answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly safer command line flag than ''--disable-web-security'' is

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

This does not completely turn off all security features. Still also this flag should not be used in productive environments...