# How to read server side csv file on load of webpage

Tags: javascript, csv, server

how do I read a server side csv file on the load of my webpage. Here is the code that I am currently using, that runs on load of the webpage:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "titles.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        processData(data);
    }
});
```

This code doesn't work giving me an error in the console of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." This doesn't make sense because the file is literally a local file to the server. I would appreciate some help. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Are you loading the webpage from the server or from a local file?

Comment: If you're loading a local file, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683600/couldnt-ajax-local-file-from-local-html-page

Comment: Nope guys, the webpage is being loaded from the server... the website is not being hosted by my computer.

Comment: Then you shouldn't get this error. It only happens when a web page tries to use AJAX to access a URL in a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

For your url value, use:

```
url: 'http://localhost/[DIRECTORY TO YOUR FILE]/titles.csv'
```

Comment: The webpage is being hosted not be me. The webpage is NOT being hosted client side on my computer.