# XMLHttpRequest responseText empty when opening a local txt file

Tags: javascript, ajax

It's an example from "DOM Scripting Web Design With js the Document Object Model"
ajax.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="new"></div>
    <script src="scripts\addLoadEvent.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts\getHTTPObject.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts\getNewContent.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

addLoadEvent.js

```
function addLoadEvent(func)
{
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if(typeof window.onload != 'function')
    {
        window.onload = func;
    }
    else{
        window.onload = function(){
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

getHttpObject,js

```
function getHTTPObject()
{
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest == 'undefined')
        XMLHttpRequest = function(){
            try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');}
                catch (e) {}
            try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0');}
                catch (e) {}
            try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');}
                catch (e) {}
            return false;
        }
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

getNewContent.js

```
function getNewContent()
{
    var request = getHTTPObject();
    if(request){
        request.open("GET","example.txt",true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(request.readyState == 4){
                if(request.status == 0){
                    var para = document.createElement("p");
                    var txt = document.createTextNode(request.responseText);
                    para.appendChild(txt);
                    document.getElementById('new').appendChild(para);
                }
            }
        };
        request.send(null);
    }else{
        alert('sorry,your browser doesn\'t support XMLHTTPRequest');
    }
}

addLoadEvent(getNewContent);
```

the `example.txt` and the `ajax.html` are in the same dir,and the `request.status=0`,
the `responseText` is always empty.What's wrong with my code?

Comment: that's how browsers roll. the HTTP in `XMLHttpRequest` should give you a hint ... it's not `XMLFileRequest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't ajax local file from local html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683600/couldnt-ajax-local-file-from-local-html-page)

Comment: Also, don't use backslashes ( \ ), use forward slashes ( / ), backslashes are invalid and will only work in browsers that correct your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I am using chrome or IE. However, when I switch to Firefox, it's amazingly all right! Someone said that it's because that Ajax is based on HTTP protocol. IE or chrome will have errors between HTTP and FILE protocol. Firefox can be compatible (the details is too complicated for me), so I just suggest using Firefox~
Also please check no typo errors in your script.