# Why isn't my button loading external page data into div?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an issue with AJAX.

I am using Safari version 12.1.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

        <!-- GoogleFonts -->

        <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

        <button>Get External Content</button>


        <!-- Imported JavaScript libraries -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>

        <!-- test Javascript files -->
        <!--<script src="assets/js/test.js"></script>-->

        <script>
            $("button").click(function(){
              $("#div1").load("ajaxload.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                if(statusTxt == "success")
                  alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if(statusTxt == "error")
                  alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
              });
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is the code for the ajaxload.html page

```
<h1>Portfolio</h1>

<p>Congratulations you have loaded content from an external page</p>
```

For some reason I keep on getting the error message.

Comment: please post the error msg as well

Comment: Error message. Error: 0: error

Comment: Are you running this on a web server or your local computer? The code presented doesn't seem to have any obvious issues, but if you try to run it from your computer AJAX will not work.

Comment: I am running it locally. Is there a way I can get it to work locally?

Comment: It can possibly be done, but this is essentially something browsers do not allow (for security purposes). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683600/couldnt-ajax-local-file-from-local-html-page) for a better explanation.